# Ajax submitHandler: form not submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have problem with Ajax submitHandler. the problem is like this,if the value is not exist then it wont allow user to submit the form and show and alert below the textbox but if data is exist form will submit. the problem i have data is exist but submithandler wont sumbit the form just return value when i debug with firebug.

Here's the form code guys:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/reward" id='myFormId' method="post">
<div class="header-content black wow fadeInLeft animated animated" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
  <div class="header-content-inner" style="text-align: center !important;">
    <div style="margin:auto;">
      <p>
        <input type="text" id="cardcodeno" name="cardcodeno" required maxlength="14" >
      </p>
      <label id="errorMesg"></label>
    </div>
    <div style="margin:auto;">
      <p>
        <input type="text" id="noponsel" name="noponsel"  required maxlength="14">
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="header-button">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="&nbsp;">
</div>
</form>
```

Here's the ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var flag = false;
  $("#myFormId").validate({
    rules:{
            noponsel:{required:true,number: true,minlength:10},
            cardcodeno:{required:true},
            metodaC:{email:true},
          },

          /*Check Data No Exist or Not*/
          submitHandler: function (form) {
            var cardcodeno = $('#cardcodeno').val();
            var isSuccess = false;

            if(!flag) {
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              url: base_url+"home/checkpassioncard",
              data: {"cardcodeno":cardcodeno}
            }).done(function (response) {
              if(response == 0) {
                $('#errorMesg').html('Data Not Exist, Please Type Correctly ');
              }else {
                flag = true;
                $('#errorMesg').html('');
                $( "#btnSubmit" ).trigger( "click" );
              }
            });
          }
            return flag;
          },

    messages:{
            noponsel:{
                required:'Phone no required',
                number  :'Only numeric',
                minlength:'min 10 char'},
            nopassioncard:{
                required:'Passion card must be fill'},
            metodaC: {
                email   :'Email must valid'},
            },
    errorElement: "p",
        wrapper: "p",  // a wrapper around the error message
    });
});
```

controller function to check data exist or not:

```
public function checkpassioncard()
{
$data = $this->input->post('cardcodeno');
$result = $this->Home_m->checkpassioncard($data);
echo $result;
}
```

and this the model guys:

```
public function checkpassioncard($data)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM  mytable WHERE cardcodeno LIKE '$data' LIMIT 1";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
      return "0";
    } else {
      return "1";
    }
}
```

===update====

it always return this when i debug with firebug
[image]

code update

```
...
              }else {
                flag = true;
                $('#errorMesg').html('');
                $( "#btnSubmit" ).click( function(){
                  $.ajax({
                    url: base_url+"home/reward",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {"noponsel":noponsel},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(result){
                      alert("test");
                      $("#myFormId").submit();
                    }
                  });
                });
              }
...
```

Comment: Try changing this line `$( "#btnSubmit" ).trigger( "click" );` to `$("#myFormId").submit();`

Comment: still same dude, the form wont submitting. u can check the update above @Glubus

Comment: Oh damn I know what's up, you see that `flag = true`? That's preventing from running the `submitHandler` more than once. By calling `$("#btnSubmit").click()` you're triggering the same piece of code again, though the above code does not at all send your form data to an endpoint where it might be stored or whatever. The only thing you're doing atm is sending it to some action that checks whether or not the form data is valid. You need to implement another `post` that actually does something with the form data. You need to implement this where you set `flag = true`.

Comment: so which mean, i need to implement another `post` for submitting form? the code place is down the `flag=true` isnt? I'm not to good with ajax :-D @Glubus

Comment: Yes you got it, I understand you did not write this code yourself, but right above that location there's already an ajax request: `$.ajax()`, the first parameter of the `$.ajax()` function is an object with different options, one of which is the URL to where the request should be sent. Just copy the `$.ajax()` thing and create an extra one after the `flag = true`, while making sure the `url : ` option is set to the endpoint where you want to handle the form data. Also, lookup jQuerys syntax for ajax requests. You can't work on this project and not know this trivial thing.

Comment: dude i have tried your suggestion, but still got the same problem like screenshot above. am i wrong with the implement? you can check my update above @Glubus